# Is there any Twitter logout API?

Tags: api, twitter, logout

I have implemented Twitter authentication in my portal. Now, when user logout to portal, I also want to `logout` user from Twitter.
Can anyone know Twitter API to logout ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot log a user out of the main Twitter site.

Do you want a user to have to re-authenticate themselves with Twitter when they next access your portal?  If so, you simply need to remove their OAuth tokens.  For example, if they're stored in a user's cookies - unset them.  If they're in your database, delete them.

Comment: Terence, I am authenticating a web portal using Twitter authentication. Now, when user logout the portal, I also want to logout user from Twitter.

Comment: Is there an answer to @Raja Shahid question?  I'm faced with a similar situation right now.